# ValueError: row index was 65536, not allowed by .xls format

Tags: python, xlwt, xlutils

Currently, I am trying to edit an existing excel file using xlwt. I do not want to edit directly on the excel, so I first make a copy.

```
new_wb = xlutils.copy(file_location)
```

From this copy, I used the xlwt module to write a new column into the newly copied excel file and save. However, I get an error when I try to copy:

```
ValueError: row index was 65536, not allowed by .xls format
```

I am a little confused because the file I duplicate is a xlsx file, not xls. I never use the xls format in my code.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `xlutils` only works with the `xls` format... (it uses the `xlrd`/`xlwt` libraries...)

Comment: `xlutils.copy` uses `xlrd` for reading and `xlwt` for writing.  `xlrd` can read both `.xls` and `.xlsx` formats, but `xlwt` only writes to `.xls` format which is limited to 65536 (2**16) rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl) instead. It support .xlsx files.

The row limit of .xls files is 65,536. xlsutils might not be supporting .xlsx files.

You can try doing this to see if it works:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
.
.
.
(make your edits)
.
.
.
wb.save('new_filename.xlsx')
```

Comment: I tried writing in openpyxl, but continued to get the MemoryError when saving. I tried read/write only formatting but wasn't sure how to apply the write only tag to existing excel files. Can the write_only = True tag also be applied to existing excel files? Basically, I was unclear on how to solve the MemoryError so rewrote my code in xlwt.

Comment: Read/write only formatting does not allow you to edit existing files. You would have to load the workbook with openpxl and save it after making your changes.

Comment: I see. Then, there would be no pay to edit on existing excel files in my situation using openpyxl or xlwt? I have a MemoryError when trying to save my Excel file with openpyxl; probably due to the large file size.

Comment: I've made some edits to my answer. You can give it a try.

Comment: @BrianKim: [Read up](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html#read-only-mode) on `openpyexcel`'s `read_only` and `write_only` modes.  They are designed to save on memory consumption but come with particular constraints (such as in a write-only workbook rows can only be added with `append()`).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. After loading my workbook and applying the write_only = True tag, wouldn't that reset the workbook and create a workbook without any sheets? I'm unable to grab the sheet from my original workbook with sheet = wb.active and get a NoneType error when trying to use the sheet to perform any action.

Answer (score 3):

Short solution for people encountering the same issue with `pandas`’ `DataFrame.to_excel()` : if you are saving into a `.xls` extension, simply change it for `.xlsx` extension.

Comment: The OP asked for xls output, not xlsx.